# The quotient of $\mathbb{C}$ under the cyclic group is the punctured plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

For $G$ is a group generated by a translation, that is,
$$G=\langle f \rangle$$
where $f(z)=z+a$ and  $a\in \mathbb{C}$.

Then consider the quotient

$$X= \mathbb{C}/G.$$

According to the uniformization theorem of Riemann surfaces, it should be biholomorphic to the punctured plane $\mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ (because the universal covering is $\mathbb{C}$ and the deck transformation group is G).

But how to prove this quotient space is biholomorphic to the punctured plane?

Comment: Neither of $\Bbb C/G$ nor $\Bbb C^*$ is simply connected: why do you say one is?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I mean the strip is simply connected. So you mean the $Bbb C/G$ is not the strip?

Comment: Is $G$ equivalent to $\{z_0^n: n\in\Bbb Z\}$ or is it literally the integer multiples of $z_0$? I'm not a big fan of $ng$ notation in group theory since that is a bit loaded in some contexts and can create confusion.. like in situations like this.

Comment: @AolongLi Indeed, that "strip" is not homeomorphic to $\Bbb C/G$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams No. I will make my question more precise.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}/G$ is a bit more than a strip, it's a cylinder. Note that you $y=x+nz_0$ and $x$ are the same point.

Comment: @CameronWilliams My interpretation of the OP's notation is that $\Bbb C/G$ is the additive quotient group $\Bbb C/\Bbb Z z_0$ (or just $\Bbb C/\Bbb Z$).

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Aha. This is making more sense now. Man group theory notation can be a real pain sometimes. Haha.

Comment: @CameronWilliams you are right, I should make my question more clear.

Comment: Hmm. Now I'm slightly more confused. Is $G$ basically just a line in the plane?

Comment: And is this a topological quotient or an algebraic quotient?

Comment: @CameronWilliams it is a  topological quotient.

Comment: @Hamed Ah. You are right. But how to prove it is biholomorphic to the puntured plane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: manipulate the exponential mapping $\exp:\mathbb{C}/2\pi i\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{C}^{\times}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $\exp: \mathbb C\to\mathbb C^\ast$ given by $z\mapsto \exp(\frac{2\pi i z}{a})$. This is a covering map with deck transformation group isomorphic to $G=\langle z+a \rangle_\mathbb Z$. By the general holomorphic covering space theory, the base space $\mathbb C^\ast$ is biholomorphic to the total space modulo the deck transformation group, which is $\mathbb C/ G$.